# Why is KDE's GTK theme overriding Microsoft edge's theme?

Tags: kubuntu, gtk

I am currently dual booting windows 11 and kubuntu and the problem arises in kubuntu.

If you go into the appearance tab of ms edge settings. You can see 3 options: GTK, Light and Dark. I am using a much darker GTK global theme but I have set ms edge's appearance to light. But for some reason every time I reopen ms edge it reverts back to my darker GTK theme(even though it shows that its using the Light appearance).
This overriding of themes really only occurs on ms edge. Both google chrome and firefox don't have this problem.

Could someone give a solution to this problem? This makes ms edge completely unusable for me with darker global themes.

Comment: Could be an edge bug. Contact microsoft support

Comment: Which GTK dark theme and light theme are you using?

Comment: Already contacted Microsoft support. They first forwarded me to Microsoft learn where they further told me to ask here

Comment: The dark theme in question is edna and the light theme is just the regular breeze theme.